# WordPress Admin bar missing from custom theme

Tags: theme-development, admin-bar

I'm working on a WP site which has a custom theme built from scratch and I can't seem to figure out how to get the Admin Bar to appear when viewing the public site.

The themes footer.php file has the wp footer code in it:
`<?php wp_footer(); ?>` just before the closing `</body>` tag.
I've tried disabling all plugins and reverting back to default theme. The Admin bar appears when using the Twenty Twenty One theme so the issue is with this custom built theme for sure. Disabling plugins had no effect.

The theme is using ACF.

I have enabled admin bar from my WordPress profile settings.

WP_DEBUG doesn't throw any errors or notices.

How could I troubleshoot this further?

Comment: Please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277190/wordpress-admin-bar-not-showing-on-frontend). Problem looks exactly the same as yours.

Comment: Thank you! The solution in this link is better than the one I found because it actually checks if the user is logged in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_true');
```

Add this at the end of functions.php

Comment: Adding it like that did not work but you pointed me in to right direction and I found the solution from the WP Code Reference page: [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/show_admin_bar/)

The correct solution was to add `add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_true');` to my functions.php file. If you want to change that to your answer I'll accept it as solution :)

Comment: glad you figured it out :) I will update the answer so it may be helpful for someone else.

Comment: Actually that added the admin bar to the public site even if the user was not logged in. There was a better solution which checks if user is logged in, found here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277190/wordpress-admin-bar-not-showing-on-frontend)

Comment: yes, you can apply check over the filter depending upon the requirements.